# Is it possible to replace individual values in an appSettings file on publish from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, configuration, publish

In my solution, there's a single appSettings.config file which is shared by a number of projects. It's referenced in the config files of those projects like this:

```
  <appSettings file="appSettings.config" />
```

And that's all fine.

The individual config files also have Debug and Release configurations that I can use to control things like connection strings when I publish from local to live and that's also fine.

However, most of the key settings I want to change aren't in the project config files: they're in that appSettings file.

I could have two appSettings files in my solution and have the Debug > Release configuration change which one is referenced when the solution is published, but that seems a little clumsy - most of the settings are the same.

Right-clicking on the appSettings.config file doesn't give me an "add config transforms" option, so I'm guessing I can't have a Debug/Release transformation of that file itself.

Is there any other way to go about this other than replacing the whole file on publish?

Comment: 1 way to do this would be to have appSettings.config, appSettings.Debug.config, appSettings.Release.config all located in a central project. Then reference said files as linked files in projects that need to know. Once you have that, you can transform the appsettings file reference as needed with your various web.config files.

Comment: If you are using an MSDeploy package you can do this in the Parameters.xml file.